# GCE: How to setup a private cloud (Firewall rules) with DynDns (No-Ip)?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm new to Google Compute Engine. I setup a VM to handle a private cloud: Only few IP address should have access to the server.

According to the documentation to setup a private cloud I have to set firewall rules to restrict access to given IP Address.

In the real world many people do not have static IP Address and use DynDNS or No-Ip. Is there a way to set a name instead of an ip in firewall rules ? Something like

```
user1.ddns.net
user2.ddns.net
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't use hostnames or any "on-fly-translator" for DyDNS and No-IP in firewall rules:

[manual for gcloud compute firewall-rules create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/firewall-rules/create)

You have to provide either source IP (IP range) or source tag. You probably have to create/write some middleware which resolve hostname and allow/disallow access.

Comment: Thanks that's what I thought :-/ (my idea was to be ultra secure so restrict using ip) It seems NGinx can be used as a middleware http://blog.zencoffee.org/2013/12/dynamic-dns-filtering-nginx/